# error when I try import DropDown react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, dropdown

When I try import dropdown

```
import {Dropdown} from 'react-native-material-dropdown'
```

give me this error:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/issues/220

Comment: thanks, you  save my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a problem with material dropdown with the latest version. you need to comment `itemTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style` in `..\node_modules\react-native-material-dropdown\src\components\dropdown` file.

And removing `Animated` in `Animated.Text.propTypes.style` in
affix/index
helper/index
label/index
of `react-native-material-textfield` and adding `import { Animated, Text} from 'react-native';` in each of above three files.

For reference please look:
https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/issues/224#issuecomment-614734400